# datatables warning requested unknown parameter id for row 0

Tags: laravel, datatable

In Controller am retuning insurance values by datatable functions

```
$Insurance = Insurance::lists('id','name');
return Datatables::of($Insurance)
->make(true);
```

and in datatable

```
ajax: "{!! URL::to('/insurances/insurancedata') !!}?id={!! $id !!}&name={!! $name !!}",
columns: [
    {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
    {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
],
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer through console. I listed `id` and `name` without column name. For this reason **datatable** raised error message. After I changed like this

```
$Insuranced = Insurance::where('id','!=','0')->select('id', 'name')->get();
```

I got output as `{{"id":"857","name":"ALICARE}`